# QTP-Object Spy does not recognize a web element correctly on different machines?

Tags: html, qtp

[image]

I am running into an issue while using  Object spy. On first machine object spy recognizes the web element correctly with inner text as "Test" on the other machine with same configuration object spy recognizes the web element's inner text as document.write(date....)etc, not only that the whole hierarchy appears to be in html.

Any suggestions?
Both machines have same IE and UFT versions

Comment: I've never heard of such a problem, can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Interesting ... Screen shot and check BHO manager add on class enabled

Comment: Added a screen shot...and yes BHO is enabled! In other machine object spy is recognizing the inner text as "01/24/2015"

Comment: @ LittlePanda No IE11